# Make windows visual code mouse copy/paste behave like linux

Tags: visual-studio-code, copy, paste

How to select text with double click in Visual Studio TEMINAL and copy to command line with 3 clicks instead of 4 clicks.

```
double click on text -> right click -> selected text in TERMINAL command line
```

instead of

```
double click on text -> right click -> right click -> selected text in TERMINAL command line
```

I have selected **terminal.integrated.copyOnSelection**, but this is not what I want.

Comment: I do not get a context menu in the Terminal, why do you need to `right-click` twice, when `right-click` in text editor I do not get this `in Terminal command line`

Comment: I would like to select text with **left double click** (in Visual Code Terminal) and paste with **one single right click** (in Visual Code Terminal). The windows command line has the same "lets say" standard behavior **left double click** to select text and to copy hit **once right click** and to paste again **right click**.

Comment: For example, PuTTY has the normal bevaiour, three simple clicks and you have text in command line. I can't get it in Visual Code. I'm using Visual Code with Kubernetes and Docker and I expect Linux behaviour : ) Any ideas?

Comment: in my windows cmd terminal it is: right-click=>Mark, select text, right-click, right-click=>Paste, 5 clicks and a select with left, in VSC cmd Integrated Terminal: select text with drag-left, right-click, right-click (paste on second right-click) double click with left does also work. I have used the terminal a lot but did not knew this.

Comment: cmd -> Properties -> Options -> Edit Options and add tick to QuickEdit Mode. You don't need to use Mark if QuickEdit Mode was set.

Comment: So, I figured out, that left mouse double on text in VS Code selects text and Shift+Insert puts text to command line. Still, I'm looking for paste with one right mouse click.

Answer (score 2):

Romasius I think what you're looking for is terminal.integrated.rightClickBehavior and change that setting to 'paste' instead of 'copypaste'.